# How to add onclick event for info boxes into pushpins on bingmaps in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, bing-maps

I managed to position all the coordinates with pushpins on the map, now I want to create event when click on the pushPins to show infobox ?

**Can I get a example how to hide infoboxes and show only infobox when click on the pushPins ?**

My code:

```
import React from 'react';

import { ReactBingmaps } from 'react-bingmaps';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">

        <ReactBingmaps
          bingmapKey="AnK1IGWE20I4jxXYE6lqu5sPHf9rQR5OEBs1vyrXBt6LGy4HpbAHqc0kGvq1pFpf"
          center={[42.6170006, 25.3999996]}
          zoom={8}
          mapTypeId={"aerial"}



          pushPins={
            [
              { 'location': [41.19197, 25.33719], 'option': { color: 'yellow' }, },
              { 'location': [41.26352, 25.1471], 'option': { color: 'yellow' }, },
              { 'location': [41.26365, 25.24215], 'option': { color: 'yellow' }, },
              { 'location': [41.26369, 25.33719], 'option': { color: 'yellow' }, },
            ]
          }

          infoboxes={
            [
              {
                "location": [42.6170006, 25.3999996], "option": { title: '№ на станция', description: '...' }
              },
              {
                "location": [42.43278, 25.64194], "option": { title: '№ на станция', description: '...' }
              }
            ]
          }
        >
        </ReactBingmaps>
      </header>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Now when I start the project infoboxes is openned, I want to hide this infoboxes at start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's quite easy actually. You can achieve that by using a prop called `infoboxesWithPushPins` which is an `array` of `objects`, where you can specify an `addHandler` like `click`,`mouseover` etc.

For example:

```
import React from 'react';

import { ReactBingmaps } from 'react-bingmaps';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">

        <ReactBingmaps
          bingmapKey="AnK1IGWE20I4jxXYE6lqu5sPHf9rQR5OEBs1vyrXBt6LGy4HpbAHqc0kGvq1pFpf"
          center={[42.6170006, 25.3999996]}
          zoom={8}
          mapTypeId={"aerial"}

          infoboxesWithPushPins = {[
            {
              "location":[41.19197, 25.33719], 
              "addHandler": "click", //on click the pushpin, infobox shown
              "infoboxOption": { title: '№ на станция', description: '...' },
              "pushPinOption":{ color: 'yellow' },
            },
          ]
          }
        >
        </ReactBingmaps>
      </header>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I just tried with one of your coordinates, now you just need to add the other one's. Cheers.

Comment: How can I import a react-recharts or something element from react into infoboxes ?